# Chef fails when trying to deploy a Torquebox app on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, torquebox

I'm pretty new to Chef/ops in general but I'm trying to deploy on EC2 and I keep running into this error.  The stack trace file mentioned in the error does not exist so that's making it kind of hard to debug the problem.  Also, whenever Chef fails, the permission on my EC2 box gets denied and I have to spin up a new instance.  For reference, the original source of this file is from here: http://janitor.se/blog/2013/07/04/easier-neo4j-dot-rb-deployments-with-chef-plus-capistrano-plus-torquebox/

The error looks like this:

```
  * script[install torquebox backstage] action run
    - execute "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20131011-2067-1phzfkw"

[2013-10-11T03:47:51+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-10-11T03:47:51+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-10-11T03:47:51+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 71 resources updated
[2013-10-11T03:47:51+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
ERROR: RuntimeError: chef-solo failed. See output above.
```

My recipe file - torquebox.rb:

```
download_file = File.join("/tmp", File.basename(node.torquebox.download_url))

remote_file download_file do
  source  node.torquebox.download_url
  mode 00644
  action :create_if_missing
  notifies :run, "script[install-torquebox]", :immediately
end

script "install-torquebox" do
  Chef::Log.info("Installing torquebox zip file...")
  user 'torquebox'
  interpreter "bash"
  code <<-EOH
  unzip -o #{download_file} -d /opt/torquebox/
  ln -s /opt/torquebox/torquebox-2.3.2 /opt/torquebox/current
  EOH
  notifies :run, "execute[change ownership to torquebox]"
  not_if do
    File.exists? "/opt/torquebox/torquebox-2.3.2"
  end
  # not_if do
  #    File.exists? "/opt/torquebox/torquebox-2.2.0"
  #  end
  #action :nothing
end


template "/etc/profile.d/torquebox.sh" do
  source "torquebox.sh.erb"
  mode 00644
  owner 'root'
  variables(
    :jboss_user =>  node[:torquebox_env][:jboss_user],
    :torquebox_home => node[:torquebox_env][:home],
    :jboss_pidfile => node[:torquebox_env][:jboss_pidfile],
    :jboss_console_log => node[:torquebox_env][:jboss_console_log],
    :jboss_config => node[:torquebox][:configuration_file],
    :jruby_opts => node[:torquebox_env][:jruby_opts],
    :java_environment_file => node[:java][:java_environment]
  )
  notifies :restart, "service[jboss-as-standalone]"
end


# install torquebox backstage
#
execute "change ownership to torquebox" do
  user "root"
  cwd "/opt"
  Chef::Log.info("changing ownership for torquebox")
  command "chown -Rv 1000.1000 /opt/torquebox"
  notifies :run, "script[install torquebox backstage]"
  action :nothing
end

script "install torquebox backstage" do
  Chef::Log.info("Installing torquebox backstage file...")
  interpreter "bash"
  user "torquebox"
  cwd "/opt/torquebox"
  code <<-EOH
  export TORQUEBOX_HOME=/opt/torquebox/torquebox-2.3.2
  export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk7/
  export JBOSS_HOME=$TORQUEBOX_HOME/jboss
  export JRUBY_HOME=$TORQUEBOX_HOME/jruby
  export PATH=$JBOSS_HOME/bin:$JRUBY_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  EOH
  # jruby -S gem install torquebox-backstage
  # jruby -S gem install ruby-shadow
  # jruby -S backstage deploy
  not_if do
    File.exists? "/opt/torquebox/current/jruby/bin/backstage"
  end
end

directory '/opt/apps/' do
  owner "torquebox"
  group "torqubox"
  mode 00755
  action :create
  not_if do
    File.exists? "/opt/apps/"
  end
end

directory "/etc/jboss-as" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 00755
  action :create
  not_if do
    File.exists? "/etc/jboss-as"
  end
end

directory "/var/log/jboss-as" do
  owner "torquebox"
  group "torquebox"
  mode 00755
  action :create
  not_if do
    File.exists? "/var/log/jboss-as"
  end
end

template "/etc/init.d/jboss-as-standalone" do
  source "jboss-as-standalone.sh.erb"
  variables(:environment_file => node[:torquebox][:environment_file])
  mode 00755
  owner 'root'
  notifies :restart, "service[jboss-as-standalone]"
end


service "jboss-as-standalone" do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :stop => true, :start => true
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end

#if clustered then if cluster name is staging_cluster, so proxy name will be staging_cluster_proxy
#so for every cookbook, it should be paired with two of them
proxy_nodes = []
clustered_nodes = []

Chef::Log.warn("clustered status #{node[:torquebox][:clustered]}")
if node[:torquebox][:clustered]
  clustered_nodes =  search(:node, "roles:#{node[:torquebox][:cluster_name]}")
  proxy_nodes = search(:node, "roles:#{node[:torquebox][:cluster_name]}_proxy")

  template "/opt/torquebox/current/jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml" do
    source "standalone-ha.xml.erb"
    variables(:node_name => node.name, :node_ipaddress => node.ipaddress, :cluster_name => node[:torquebox][:cluster_name], :clustered_nodes => clustered_nodes, :proxy_nodes => proxy_nodes )
    mode "0644"
    notifies :restart, "service[jboss-as-standalone]"
  end
end

if proxy_nodes.count == 0 and node[:torquebox][:clustered] == true
  Chef::Log.warn("There is no proxy defined, cluster may not function")
end

if !node[:torquebox][:clustered]
  template "/opt/torquebox/current/jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml" do
    source "standalone.xml.erb"
    variables(:node_name => node.name, :node_ipaddress => node.ipaddress)
    mode "0644"
    notifies :restart, "service[jboss-as-standalone]"
  end
end

template "/opt/torquebox/current/jboss/bin/standalone.conf" do
  source "standalone.conf.erb"
  mode "00644"
  owner 'torquebox'
  variables(:jboss_config => node[:torquebox][:configuration_file])
  notifies :restart, "service[jboss-as-standalone]"
end

cookbook_file "/etc/jboss-as/jboss-as.conf" do
  source "jboss-as.conf"
  mode 00644
  owner 'root'
end


# NGINX!

# this enables our site, kinda like a2ensite
execute 'enable-site' do
  command "ln -sf /etc/nginx/sites-available/#{node[:server_name]} /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{node[:server_name]}"
  notifies :restart, 'service[nginx]'
end

# Our configuration template. Take a look at templates/nginx.conf.erb to see what's going on.
template "/etc/nginx/sites-available/#{node[:server_name]}" do
  source 'nginx.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 0644
  notifies :run, "execute[enable-site]", :immediately
  variables(
     server_name: node.server_name
   )
end

service 'nginx'
service 'jboss-as-standalone'
```

Comment: `/tmp/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out` should be on EC2 instance, not your local machine. Check for it there.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? If you did, you could pleae post it and mark your answer as correct? :)